# Formatting date with HtmlDisplayFor and DateTime.ToString difference

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I have issue with date formatting mimatch between what is generated by Razor in the view with `@Html.DisplayFor` and the date I want to show from ajax call.

For some reason the date which is rendered by `@Html.DisplayFor` shows the format as "2015/04/20 14:14". Then I need to update one row in the view and I make some Ajax call which returns the updated date, I call .ToString on the Date object and it returns the "3/10/2017 2:31:10 PM"

I checked the Thread cultures and they are same when the View is generated and same when it reaches controller, but for some reason `@Html.DisplayFor` shows different date format.

I don't want to have two different places with date formatting, I want to have one place of generation, I know I can just call `ToString` in `Display` method, but I would like to know WHY they differ?

Anybody know this? Thanks

Comment: Does your `DateTime` property have a `DisplayFormat` attribute?  If so that's where `@Html.DisplayFor` is getting the format to use.

Comment: No, it doesn't have any formatting set with attribute, just default behavior